# jQuery hide() Cannot get 'duration' setting to be recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can't seem to find an answer to this.

I am attempting to animate the `hide()` when hiding a `<li>` element.  I have a `<span>` inside of the `<li>` that acts as a 'delete' button.

This is the part I can't seem to get working.

```
$('#list1').on('click', 'li span', function(event) {  
  $(this).parent().hide(1000); 
});
```

The list item **IS**, in fact, being hidden.  The duration, however, is NOT taking effect.  The item is disappearing without any sort of 'animation'.

Here it is in action:  https://jsfiddle.net/scampione/effnuct0/14/

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try including jQuery -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/effnuct0/15/, jQuery Slim has no animation

Comment: Not what you're asking, but clickable span elements aren't very good from an accessibility point of view: users who are restricted to keyboard access can't click them (such users *can* "click" anchor elements).

Comment: That's how it should work, as *@adeneo* stated jQuery slim doesn't have any animation. Include normal jQuery instead and it will have animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work fine here once I included jQuery.

As noted in the comments, jQuery Slim does not contain the animation you're using. You need to include the full jQuery library.

```js
var buildArray = function(max) {
  var rtnArray = [];
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
    rtnArray.push(i);
  }
  return rtnArray;
}

var feedBack = $('.display-feedback');

var delButton = '<span class="delete-item">X</span>';

var appendToList = function(theStr) {
  var target = $('#list1')
  target.append('<li>' + theStr + delButton + '</li>')
}


$('.clear-feedback').on('click', function() {
  feedBack.empty();
});

$('#list1').on('click', 'li span', function(event) {
  $(this).parent().hide(1000);
});

$('#list1').on('click', 'li', function(event) {
  feedBack.text(event.type + " - " + event.target.nodeName + " - " + event.currentTarget);
});

var myArray = buildArray(10);
appendToList(myArray)
appendToList(myArray.map(num => num * 7));
appendToList(myArray.filter(num => num > 5));
appendToList(myArray.map(num => num * 7).filter(num => num > 35));
```

```css
.container {
  height: auto;
  border: solid 1px cornflowerblue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #717171;
}
.output-list {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 2px #77ddbb;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.output-list li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #44bbee;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.output-list > span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #a0a0a0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.delete-item {
  color: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.delete-item:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.feedback {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
.clear-feedback {
  width: 39px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #aabbcc;
  color: white;
}
.clear-feedback:hover {
  background-color: #778899;
}
.clear-feedback:active {
  background-color: #556677;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="output-list" id='list1'>
    <span>a &ltspan&gt in list 1</span>
    <li>this &ltLI&gt is from HTML
      <span class='delete-item'>X</span>
    </li>
  </ul>


  <div class="feedback">
    <div class='display-feedback'></div>
    <span class='clear-feedback'>Clear</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a really really long example. I think it would be clearer to the asker of this question if you provided the smallest reasonable code to reproduce this...

Comment: It's just his own code in a SO snippet. I could pare it down, but it's showing that the exact same code runs fine when I included jquery.

Comment: That was it !!  Thank you Jecoms and adeneo.  I was including jQuery slim.  Did not realize that it did not include animations.  Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

Hide does except a speed parameter, try getting rid if the li inside the function args and just have it say span.

Comment: Why would that help?

Comment: Well first it would make the syntax correct, because there is no reason to include the li in there. I would just use fadeOut instead, and see if that works.

Comment: @DanielZuzevich You know they have a fiddle you can modify? Also that's not the problem.

Comment: It wouldn't make the syntax "correct", because it isn't "incorrect" at the moment.

Comment: Why would you put li inside of the arg when you clearly call the parent method afterwards.

Comment: The current code says whenever a click occurs within the `'#list1'` element, if it is on an element that matches the `'li span'` selector then [do something]. So if the click occurs on a span that is *not* inside an li then don't do anything, and changing the selector to just `'span'` would change that behaviour. (Of course in this case the OP's HTML is invalid in that it has a span as a direct child of a ul element as well as the ones in the li elements, but that's another issue.) The OP's code works as is if the full jQuery is included rather than jQuery Slim.